# Check for database connection, otherwise display message

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I would like to check if the website can connect to mySQL. If not, I would like to display an error saying that the user should try to access the page again in a few minutes...

I really do not know how to do this ;)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
string mysql_error ([ resource $link_identifier ] )
```

But how do I use this?

This just gives me the error, but I want the message to display with any error.

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: thanks for the info but I dont know how I could use this (it just gives me the error) - Hi from Deutschland

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$servername   = "localhost";
$database = "database";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: Can I also place php code inside the "{
  // place error here
}" because this give me an error

Comment: so I could replace `code : echo "Please try later." ` with `code : <?php
$fade_amount = 60;                              //In Percentage
$box_width = 400;
$box_background = 'FFFFFF';             //Hex Color
$box_border_width = 1;
$box_border_color = '999999';  
$close_box = 1;          ...   `
Thanks for your help!!!! +1

Comment: Remove the `<?php` and `?>` tags from your stuff.  Also, I would remove the `die()` function.  I also refined it again to wrap the success stuff in the `else` block.

Comment: Nice! This could lead me to [this connection error solution](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1390): `mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client `

Comment: How is this supposed to work if `$database` is never used?

Comment: @JasonSwett - When this was edited to support the new `mysqli` library, it looks like that information was dropped.  I just edited it back to pass the database as part of the constructor.

Comment: And for the record, calling `die()` should be avoided at all costs. Replace that with your own error handling logic.

Answer (score 6):

very basic:

```
<?php 
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$server = 'localhost'; 
// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password) or die('try again in some minutes, please');
//if you want to suppress the error message, substitute the connection line for:
//$connection = @mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die('try again in some minutes, please');
?>
```

result:

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /home/user/public_html/zdel1.php on line 6
try again in some minutes, please

as per Wrikken's recommendation below, check out a complete error handler for more complex, efficient and elegant solutions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: Please, do not die..... Echo an error message, but the use `trigger_error('some internal error message',E_USER_ERROR);`, that way, the error shows up in your logs, as you are unlikely to be the one to catch it yourself on a busy site. Of course, this also assumes `log_errors` to be on, and `display_errors` to be off, which should be the default for any production environment.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this:

```
$servername='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$databasename='MyDb';

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password);

if (!$connection) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

/*mysqli_query($connection, "DROP DATABASE if exists MyDb;");

if(!mysqli_query($connection, "CREATE DATABASE MyDb;")){
echo "Error creating database: " . $connection->error;
}

mysqli_query($connection, "use MyDb;");
mysqli_query($connection, "DROP TABLE if exists employee;");

$table="CREATE TABLE employee (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)"; 
$value="INSERT INTO employee (firstname,lastname,email) VALUES ('john', 'steve', 'johnsteve@yahoo.com')";
if(!mysqli_query($connection, $table)){echo "Error creating table: " . $connection->error;}
if(!mysqli_query($connection, $value)){echo "Error inserting values: " . $connection->error;}*/
```