# How to connect to SQL Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have this code which I use in order to connect to SQL Server.

```
$host="";
$uid="sa";
$passVal="";
odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;",$uid, $passVal);
```

How should I check the connection?
I mean what should I put in my code? like:

> If connection was set then output "connected" else "disconnected"

And, how can I select the database here?
Should it be something like:

```
$database="";
odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;",$uid, $passVal, $database);
```

Comment: This question may have already been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9026712/1899595

Comment: except that that's another thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$host;Database=$database;",$uid, $passVal, ) or  die("Connection could not established");
```

For you reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

Comment: I get this message...:

Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: I USE IT LIKE THIS:
odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database;",$uid, $passVal) or  die("Connection could not established");

Comment: And get the error:
 odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "montim"

Comment: tHANKS, BUT THE ISSUE IS, IT DOESN'T ALLOW ME TO ENTER THE DATABASE...
the issue might be there!

Comment: and i get this:
Warning: odbc_connect() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given in

Comment: you have to give correct database name and correct password. Please check value for $uid and $passVAl.

Comment: Oops, Please run the updated code,I had put the database name at wrong place.

Comment: last question, could you give me a hint?
i get the message:
 Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Comment: This may be coming due to wrong password for user for the given database. You must check you user name, password, database name.

Comment: To be sincere it didn't, but i suppose your answer is right, the issue is in the permissions i guess

Comment: Ok.I think you did not provide access for the given user for that database. Check privileges for that user